# How to solve "Time Machine did not finish backing up because some files were unavailable. Backups will resume when your Mac is unlocked."

Tags: macbook-pro, backup, time-machine

My Time Machine hasn't been able to backup properly for a couple of weeks now and I got this error:

> "Time Machine did not finish backing up because some files were unavailable. Backups will resume when your Mac is unlocked."

Does anyone know what that means? I have never seen it and don't know what is mean by "when your Mac is unlocked." What is locked though?
This is an M1 Pro 14 Inch 2021 running Monterey 12.0.1
My last backup was October 16, so that's more than a month ago and I don't know if that extended period of time has to do with anything. Usually I backup every 1-2 weeks, but I've been busy lately.
Thank you very much

Comment: I can't figure it out either. The `log` command people suggest will help in some instances of failure, but not all. After years of fighting Time Machine issues, I think it's time for me to throw in the towel. Apple isn't serious about Time Machine. They just want to keep pushing their paid iCloud Drive product. I think Carbon Copy Cloner and maybe restic/rclone are the best alternate options.

Comment: I just got this error for the first time ever while attempting a "first backup" onto a new Synology NAS drive. I'm running macOS 14.3.1 and already have "Prevent automatic sleeping on power adapter when display is off" enabled.